# Did God consult anyone in the assessment of Creation?

Tags: genesis, theistic-evolution, creationists

We read in Gen 1:31:  God saw all that he had made, and it was very good. And there was evening, and there was morning—the sixth day.

By human standards, certificate of excellence in relation to something made, is given by a third party which  assesses the product independently or in consultation with the manufacturer. Going by Gen 1: 26 ( "Let us make man in our image ")
the entire Trinity was involved in Creation . Genesis does not record if God consulted anyone say, the Angels, in the assessment of  Creation. How do Creationists address this issue ? Do the Theistic- evolutionists  have something to say from their perspective ?

Comment: It's true that fallible humans need external approval. But I don't see how God could need validation.

Comment: I have requested for the view points of Theistic Evolutionists with a purpose. Could it be possible that the Day One, Day Two etc in Genesis actually stand for the final day of creation of birds,  fishes, animals etc., through a slow and steady process, spread out through ages,  done with the active support of God- made natural forces  , and that God was actually appreciating  the work those forces had done on his behalf ?

Answer (score 3):

**Did God consult anyone in the assessment of Creation?**

The short answer is **no**.

God did not consult anyone at all, for God is omnipotent and all knowing and he created the universe and all it contains from nothing. Even the angels were part of his creation.

> [**creatio ex nihilo**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatio_ex_nihilo) ("creation out of nothing") is the doctrine that matter is not eternal but had to be created by some divine creative act. It is a theistic answer to the question of how the universe came to exist. It is in contrast to Ex nihilo nihil fit or "nothing comes from nothing", which means that all things were formed from preexisting things; an idea by the Greek philosopher Parmenides (c. 540 – c. 480 BC) about the nature of all things, and later more formally stated by Titus Lucretius Carus (c. 99 – c. 55 BC).
>
> Ex nihilo nihil fit means that nothing comes from nothing. In ancient creation myths, the universe is formed from eternal formless matter, namely the dark and still primordial ocean of chaos. In Sumerian myth this cosmic ocean is personified as the goddess Nammu "who gave birth to heaven and earth" and had existed forever; in the Babylonian creation epic Enuma Elish pre-existent chaos is made up of fresh-water Apsu and salt-water Tiamat, and from Tiamat the god Marduk created Heaven and Earth; in Egyptian creation myths a pre-existent watery chaos personified as the god Nun and associated with darkness, gave birth to the primeval hill (or in some versions a primeval lotus flower, or in others a celestial cow); and in Greek traditions the ultimate origin of the universe, depending on the source, is sometimes Oceanus (a river that circles the Earth), Night, or water.
>
> To these can be added the account of the Book of Genesis, which opens with God creating the heavens and the earth, separating and restraining the waters, not creating the waters themselves out of nothing. Alternately, whether this is truly 'ex nihilo', is unclear. The Hebrew sentence which opens Genesis, Bereshit bara Elohim et hashamayim ve'et ha'aretz, can be interpreted in at least three ways:
>
> 1. As a statement that the cosmos had an absolute beginning (In the beginning, God created the heavens and earth).
> 2. As a statement describing the condition of the world when God began creating (When in the beginning God created the heavens and the earth, the earth was untamed and shapeless).
> 3. As background information (When in the beginning God created the heavens and the earth, the earth being untamed and shapeless, God said, Let there be light!).
>
> It has been known since the Middle Ages that on strictly linguistic and exegetical grounds option 1 is not the preferred translation. Our society sees the origin of matter as a question of crucial importance, but for ancient cultures this was not the case, and the authors of Genesis wrote of creation they were concerned with God bringing the cosmos into operation by assigning roles and functions.
>
> **Creatio ex nihilo**: the creation of matter
>
> *Creatio ex nihilo*, in contrast to ex nihilo nihil fit, is the idea that matter is not eternal but was created by God at the initial cosmic moment. In the second century a new cosmogony arose, articulated by Plotinus, that the world was an emanation from God and thus part of God. This view of creation was repugnant to Christian church fathers as well as to Arabic and Hebrew philosophers, and they forcefully argued for the otherness of God and his creation and that God created all things from nothing by the word of God. The first articulation of the notion of creation ex nihilo is found in the 2nd century writing To Autocylus (2.10) authored by Theophilus of Antioch. By the beginning of the 3rd century the tension was resolved and creation ex nihilo had become a fundamental tenet of Christian theology. Theophilus of Antioch is the first post New Testament author to unambiguously argue for an ontological ex nihilo creation from nothing, contrasting it to the views of Plato and Lucretius who asserted clearly that matter was preexistent.
>
> In modern times some Christian theologians argue that although the Bible does not explicitly mention creation ex nihilo, it gains validity from having been held by so many for so long; and others find support in modern cosmological theories surrounding the Big Bang. Some examine alternatives to creatio ex nihilo, such as the idea that God created from his own self or from Christ, but this seems to imply that the world is more or less identical with God; or that God created from pre-existent matter, which at least has biblical support, but this implies that the world does not depend on God for its existence.
>
> In Christian metaphysics, the cosmological argument states in summary:
>
> 1. Everything that exists must have a cause.
> 2. The universe exists.
> 3. Therefore, the universe must have a cause.
>
> The Kalam cosmological argument is a modern formulation of the cosmological argument for the existence of God:
>
> 1. Everything that begins to exist has a cause.
> 2. The universe began to exist.
> 3. Therefore, the universe has a cause.
> 4. If the universe has a cause, then a changeless and eternal creator possessing free will might exist and chose to cause the creation of the universe.

God Creating the universe and all it contains was done by his own supreme will and intelligence without consulting anyone!

Answer (score 1):

The angels are also part of creation, when God the Father, came up with the idea of creation and made it known to the other two, at this point in eternity angels did not exist, neither did the world or any thing that can be considered created. Only immortal beings existed. The angels came into existence when God completed the creation of his dwelling which is heaven. Then some unknown time passed and God created us in his own image.

The will of God in terms of creation needs all of the three to participate and that is why no angels were ever consulted. Angels are created beings and not worthy of such a privilege. That privilege is enjoyed by The Father, The Son and The Holy Spirit.

Comment: Thanks, FAMI. Who are the ' immortal beings' you have referred to in para 1 of you answer ?

Comment: The angels were on hand to applause the setting of the foundations of the earth.  Physical universe was created after spirit creatures were made.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan  Good point. The word immortal is very different from the word eternal

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan, Jesus Christ and the Holy Spirit. God is one in three and three in one. God is immortal so are all of them.

Comment: Being immortal does not mean without a beginning.

Comment: @User14, Is the Holy Spirit God in your terms?

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel.  No only yhwh is God in my terms only yhwh is eternally existing

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel Holy Spirit is not a “person” but the active force of YHWH

Comment: @User 14. Since you believe Jesus Christ before he incarnated as a man was Michael the arc angel you would have to agree that he was among the other angels that "applauded the setting of the foundations of the earth" at Job 38:7. I have one question for you? Please reconcile Job 38:7 with Colossians 1:16  "For by Him/Jesus Christ all things were created, both in the heavens and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities--all things have been created by Him and for Him."  Was Jesus as Michael a cheerleader/applauding  or was Jesus Christ the creator?

Comment: @Mr.Bond God used his only begotten son as the instrument of creation God is creator his son the instrument through whom creation is accomplished. As you well know

Answer (score 1):

God speaks by the prophet Isaiah and makes it clear whether he needs consultation or approbation :

> 13 Who hath directed the Spirit of the LORD, or being his counseller hath taught him?
>
> 14 With whom took he counsel, and who instructed him, and taught him in the path of judgment, and taught him knowledge, and shewed to him the way of understanding?
>
> 15 Behold, the nations are as a drop of a bucket, and are counted as the small dust of the balance: behold, he taketh up the isles as a very little thing.

[Isaiah 40 : 13-15 KJV](https://biblehub.com/kjv/isaiah/40.htm)

Comment: Thanks,Nigel J. My question is not on whether God needed to consult someone. Need or the absence of it does not preclude God's right to consult. In the OT times it was unimaginable that the Son of God would one day be thrashed and spat upon. But God chose to let it happen. Similarly, if God chose someone to be of  his company in appraisal of the Creation, he would do it.